# How to change layout of a legend in Show function?

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to combine two plots using the Show function and have the resulting legend appear as a row. Using the LegendLayout function for each individual plot is not working. Below is my code:

```
Plot300 = 
  Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Style["Hello"]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"],
    PlotStyle -> Blue];
Plot400 = 
  Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{Style["Hello2"]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
   PlotStyle -> Green];
P1=Show[Plot300, Plot400]
```

Is there a straightforward solution to this problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are workarounds acceptable?

Comment: @bmf Potentially, yes! Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible workaround is to use the `Labeled` function and build up a legend according to your requirements.

```
Plot300 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Plot400 = Plot[Exp[-0.09*t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Green];
P1 = Labeled[
  Show[Plot300, Plot400]
  , LineLegend[
   {Blue, Green}
   , {Style["Hello2"], Style["Hello"]}
   , LegendLayout -> "Row"
   ]
  , Bottom
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the Labeled function needed here?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. One of my thoughts, as I was composing this answer, was that it allows the addition of a legend independent of the plots.

Comment: Oh I understand! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

```
aux = {"Hi bmf", "Hi mathbioguy. I hope you'll find this useful"};
aux1 = Map[Style[#, 13] &, Table[aux[[i]], {i, 1, Length@aux}]];
pos = Bottom;
f1[x_] := Exp[-0.03*x]
f2[x_] := x^2
plot1 = Plot[f1[x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 4}}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{aux[[1]]}], pos], 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed, Thick}];
plot2 = Plot[f2[x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 4}}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{aux[[2]]}], pos], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

> [image: plot]