How to change positioning of legends using Show command?
In reference to "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267013/how-to-change-layout-of-a-legend-in-show-function", the solution is provided. My question is:
If I have 5 curves each in plot300 and plot400, which corresponds to 5 legend points in each. Now I plotted them separately where I used a command Plot[PlotLegends->Placed["Expressions",Below]]. While combining the two plots, I used Show[plot300,plot400].The output here shows the legends placed below the graph in one single row.
Is it possible to place legend points such that it takes 2 rows displaying 5 points each, while using the show command? Basically, the legends should be within the width of the graph and should not extend beyond it.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

func300 = Exp[-#*t] & /@ Range[0.01, 0.09, 0.02];

func400 = Exp[-#*t] & /@ Range[0.02, 0.1, 0.02];

Plot300 = Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ func300], {t, 0, 100},
   PlotStyle -> "SolarColors"];
Plot400 = Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ func400], {t, 0, 100},
   PlotStyle -> "LakeColors"];

P1 = Legended[
  Show[Plot300, Plot400],
  Placed[
   LineLegend[
    Join[
     ColorData["SolarColors"][#] & /@ Subdivide[4],
     ColorData["LakeColors"][#] & /@ Subdivide[4]],
    Join[func300, func400],
    LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}],
   Below]]


